# MVC Arranging items in a row

Tags: html, css, razor, model-view-controller

So I'm displaying items from a list, on internet explorer 8 it looks like below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Yet on Internet Explorer 9 its layed out differently, like below:

```
1 
2
3
4
5
```

I've noticed than when I remove the fieldset it fixes the issue, but I would like a way around it without having to remove the fieldset.

View

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <fieldset style="width:399px; height:210px; border:1px; border-color:Black; background-color:White">    
    <tr>
        <td> <div class="box"><a href=@Url.Action("Bid", "Items", new { id = item.ItemsID })>
        <img alt ="@item.title" width="200px" height="200px" src="@Url.Content(@item.image1)" /></a></div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="box"><br /><br />   <b>Title : </b>@Html.ActionLink(@item.title, "Bid", "Items", new { id = item.ItemsID }, "") 
        <br /><b>Artist : </b>@item.artist<br />
        <b>Condition : </b>@item.condition<br /><b>Current bid : </b>@if (item.currentBid == 0){  <font color="#E60000"><b>No bids</b></font> }else
        { <font color="#E60000"><b>£@item.currentBid</b></font> }<br /><p></p>
        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>   
    </fieldset>
}
```

CSS

```
.box  
{
padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
width:210px;
float: left;
height:150px;
}
```

Comment: Your `fieldset` width is 399px and your `.box` 210px. It shouldn't align properly.

Comment: I tried setting both to the same width but the problem still occurs, any other suggestions?

Comment: You have to set `fieldset` width to `box` * 3.

Comment: Unfortunately this only made the fieldset bigger and did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing here is creating a `<fieldset>` for every item in your model. You are then creating a table row within that fieldset, meaning you have a new row for each item. On top of that you are then trying to cram two `div` elements with a class of `.box`, which are 210px in width, into the aforementioned fieldset whose width is 399px. This isn't going to work.

I would question the need to use fieldsets or tables for what you are trying to achieve, and would avoid using `<br />` as a means of laying out your page (and `<font>` tags, and logic within your view...) but these are things for you to study away from this question.

Without fixing all the issues I have with your code, I would do something like the following (it's by no means perfect but it demonstrates my proposal):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box-image">
                <a href=@Url.Action("Bid", "Items", new { id = item.ItemsID })>
                    <img alt ="@item.title" src="@Url.Content(@item.image1)">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="box-text">
                <span><b>Title : </b>@Html.ActionLink(@item.title, "Bid", "Items", new { id = item.ItemsID }, "")</span>
                <span><b>Artist : </b>@item.artist</span>
                <span><b>Condition : </b>@item.condition</span>
                <span><b>Current Bid : </b>
                    @if (item.currentBid == 0){ 
                        <font color="#E60000"><b>No bids</b></font>
                    } else {
                        <font color="#E60000"><b>£@item.currentBid</b></font>
                    }
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Based on what you provided, my CSS would look something like:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1200px;
}
.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    width: 396px;
}
.box-image {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.box-image a {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    outline: none;
}
.box-text {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 60px;
    width: 196px;
}
span {
    display: block;
}
```

In order to ensure your items are displayed in rows of three I have had to include a fixed-width 'wrapper' outside the `@foreach` loop. If you are aiming for a fully responsive site this is not the way to go, but for the purposes of this demonstration I included it.

I have knocked together a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qpc21be/1/) of how it would look when repeated nine times, but I am making some assumptions on your layout plans based on the CSS provided in your question. I checked this solution across multiple versions of IE, along with Firefox and Chrome, and it works fine for me.